# What is the benefit of writing C function in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I am curious when and why we should write C function in Objective C code. I see some of the code where the C function could be replaced by a Objective C class level method.

I tried to google this but did not get much useful information. Please give me some simple examples where we should use a C function.

Comment: Importing existing C code that you prefer not to rewrite in Objective C.

Comment: For example getting a simple function reference is a big harder with Obj-C methods. Some C APIs need function references. Or any code that is working with `structs`. C is part of Objective-C. You don't need to use objects for everything.

Comment: Generally, when writing Objective-C app, you stay within Objective-C. You generally only drop into C when solving very specific problems. If you have examples where you’re unclear why there is a C function in Objective-C project, please edit your question to share those examples with us.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth to consider how they exactly differ.

#### Performance

Extra steps of a Objective-C method call vs a C function call include:

1. passing "hidden" arguments: instance/class as the 1st argument and the selector name as the 2nd argument.
2. optionally traversing the class hierarchy to find the one actually having the implementation
3. a lookup in
   the selector cache to find the relevant `IMP`.

All of it takes time, so a C function call will always happen marginally faster. Example of an area where it may matter is audio processing.

#### Nontrivial reverse engineering

Selector names are a giveaway of what a Objective-c method does, so it's a bit harder to analyze what a C function does. You have greater flexibility too to further conceal the invocation (before resorting to asm).

#### Inability to swizzle

It's very hard to hook a C function, but it's so easy to replace/hook implementation of an objective method. Nowadays nondynamic direct objective-c methods do exist to counter that (`__attribute__((objc_direct))`) but that's very recent objc language evolution.

#### Special use cases for C functions

Apart from obvious `main` entry point other examples include:
- signal handlers
- code executed before `+ (void)initialize;` and `main` for C functions marked with `__attribute__((constructor))`
- threading operations requiring ultra precise timing